# JSON Parse Error Garble

Tags: jquery, .net, web-services

I am trying to call a asmx webservice from client code using jquery. However I'm finding it very difficult to actually achieve this. Can anyone help?

What is happening:

1. JsonConvert is a library I use made by NewtonSoft to convert the object to json for
   returning.
2. The asmx is being hosted on domain b.company.com
3. The client ajax call is hosted on domain a.compay.com
4. Fiddler is picking up for the single call two(2) 401 then a 200 which is not viewable in the JSON tab of the reply.

This is the asmx code:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string PingCRM()
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Status = "OK",
                Data = "Hello CRM"
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Status = "ERROR",
                Data = ex
            });
        }
    }
```

This is a ajax jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('ajax success');

                console.log('result = [' + result + ']');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var txtError = 'status = [' + status + ']; Respsonse = [' + xhr.responseText + ']; Respsonse = [' + error + ']';
                console.log(txtError);
            }
        });
```

This is the fiddler "Raw" view of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-UA-Compatible: IE=9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAACWCH0UgarqcwAAAAA=
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 22:47:12 GMT
Content-Length: 127
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://b.company.com/">{"Status":"OK","Data":"Hello CRM"}</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is compressed (see the response header: `Content-Encoding: gzip`). Fiddler should be able to decompress that for you, usually by clicking a bar on top of the response (see below). If you don't see that, try upgrading to a newer version of Fiddler.

[image: Fiddler response with gzip encoding]

*Edit after update in the question*: now the problem you have is that the response is not in JSON format, but XML (with the JSON inside the XML document), so `$.ajax` won't be able to parse it for you in the `result` parameter. You can either try to change the server to actually return JSON instead of XML, or you can get the response text from the `jqXHR` object which is passed as the third argument to the `success` function, extract the JSON from the XML and parse it into the result yourself.

Comment: Ok: how do I change the server?

Comment: I haven't worked with ASMX services; that would be a question to be asked with that tag...